# How to edit existing tab url in chrome through powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to edit the url in an existing chrome tab every minute so they can switch through each other automatically using Powershell.

I have already done it where it switches through different tabs but i need to to be on the same tab because it needs to be used with chromecast, and only one tab can be casted at a  time.

Comment: Might be good to update your question with what you are currently trying and why it is different to all the duplicates :-)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has no COM interface, so you won't be able to control it without help of external resources.

I've never used it but with the chromedriver and selenium it should work:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started 
https://tech.mavericksevmont.com/blog/powershell-selenium-automate-web-browser-interactions-part-i/